# Set automatic timeout based on number of http requests sent

Tags: c#, uwp, httprequest, httpclient, proxy-server

I'm trying to develop an http proxy server for a UWP application using C# as a portable dll.However the retry timeout is 60 seconds independent of the number of requests sent, say 4 requests are sent but if it has to retry I have to wait for 60 seconds for a small number of tasks.Is there any way that I can automate how this retry timeout such that optimum timeout is used based on number of requests, maybe something​ declared globally can be used and called within the sendasync(used to send requests)?

Comment: Hello Jay! I'm really sorry for not giving you an update on my problem. I'm using system.net.http.httpclient and yes I understood what you were trying to convey, I set the timeout before requests are retried in the sendasync method to 60 seconds, when I send a few requests say 4 I want it to be retired after possibly 20 seconds. This is where I needed to automate my retry timeout based on number of requests.

Comment: The timeout can only be set before sending requests. If your request has been sent, then there is no way to change the timeout.

Comment: Oh sorry Jay I think you misunderstood me.I think it's best I demonstrate through an example.Now say I'm sending N requests, for this the timeout is 60 seconds if N>30 and timeout is 30 seconds if N<30 or something more specific.I need to implement code for this logic or something more specific.Could you give me your email id so that I can provide you more details?

Comment: Then you should be able to use a global variable to store the number of the requests you want to send and then set cancellation token according to the number.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, there are two `HttpClient` we can use to send HTTP request. They are [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient). I'm not sure which one you are using.

For [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx),  there are two ways to set a timeout. To set a timeout for all requests made from that client, we can use [HttpClient.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
var myClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
myClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

To set a timeout on a single request, use the cancellation token pattern:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var resourceUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");

try
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri, cts.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
   // Handle request being canceled due to timeout.
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
   // Handle other possible exceptions.
}
```

For [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient), there is no timeout property on the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient type. As a result, you must use the cancellation token pattern shown above.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
var resourceUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");

try
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri).AsTask(cts.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    // Handle request being canceled due to timeout.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle other possible exceptions.
}
```

For more info, please see [Demystifying HttpClient APIs in the Universal Windows Platform](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/).